# Generate a Migration to Create a Table that Joins 3 Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables and I want to create new table that stores the following:

```
user_id 
project_id 
company_id
```

I've tried through this command, but it does not work:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserProjectCompany 
    user:referencess project:referencess company:referencess
```

What do you recommend?

Comment: How they are related?Post your `models` with associations.

Comment: You have misspelled the `referencess` it should be `references`

Comment: I've tried the following command but migration file generate empty change method 

`rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserProjectCompany user:references project:references company:references`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a migration alone does not use the column parameters unless you want to add or remove a column to an existing model. You would need to generate a model to accomplish what you are trying to do (almost). For example:

```
rails g model UserProjectCompany user:references project:references company:references
```

This will generate following migration:

```
class CreateUserProjectCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_project_companies do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :project
      t.references :company

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :user_project_companies, :user_id
    add_index :user_project_companies, :project_id
    add_index :user_project_companies, :company_id
  end
end
```

But do note that you will have to add `:id => false` and remove `t.timestamps` if you don't need those.

Another thing is that it will also generate a model named "UserProjectCompanies" and some specs for it.

Comment: You **can** generate a migration that doesn't just add columns to or remove columns from a table. Try the migration in my answer, which creates a table with those three columns. But it's definitely a good call to make a model for this specific table, which I did not have in my answer. +1 for you!

Comment: You are correct. It does generate migration with columns in the latest version of Rails. In Rails 3, it just creates a file with empty `change` method. This is probably true for older version of Rails 4 as well.

Comment: Oh interesting. Yeah I only tested it on Rails 4. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually sure how generate the migration to create a join table with only those three columns, **and** id column. Obviously we can edit the generated migration and edit it (which I'll do in my answer), but where's the fun in that?

That having been said, and all fun apparently removed, I'd suggested creating an entire table, including id column, even though you may not think you need it. It may come in handy (which of these two u-p-c's was created first, I need to put this model in a nested form, etc.). To create a table that includes the id, you can simply run the following command.

```
rails g migration CreateUserProjectCompany user:references project:references company:references
```

Running the created migration will create a table that looks like:

```
id | user_id | project_id | company_id
```

To create the table without id, you'll unfortunately need to edit the migration. Replace this line...

```
create_table :user_project_companies do |t|
```

...with this one.

```
create_table :user_project_companies, id: false do |t|
```

I.E., add `, id: false` after the table name, which specifies that the table should not have an `id` column. Running this migration will give you that table with only the three columns.

```
user_id | product_id | company_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you made typo error referencess, instead use references

```
 rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserProjectCompany user:references project:references company:references
```

Comment: Sorry I've tried this but generated empty change method